# How can I run Tkinter GUI with another scheduler program together?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have coded one `Tkinter GUI` as a console to control something. And, I also want to run one scheduler from `APScheduler` module to do one job, which will do one operation every 20 seconds.
But, it seems that these 2 thread cannot operate together.

I have tried to use `multi-threading`, but it seems does not work.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time
import pyHook
import winreg
import webbrowser
import os
import pyautogui
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import  BackgroundScheduler
import threading

def initialization():
    webbrowser.open('AutoRefreshSCMOutbound.HTML', 1)
    time.sleep(2)


def autoClick():
    x, y = pyautogui.size()
    pyautogui.click(x/2, y/2, button='left')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(x/2, y/2, button='left')
    return True

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('700x100')
root.resizable(height = True, width = True)
root.overrideredirect(False)

OneBtn = Button(root, command = initialization, text = "One Button", width = '30')
OneBtn.grid(row = 1 ,column = 0)   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    th01 = threading.Thread(target=root.mainloop())
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler
    scheduler.add_job(autoClick, 'interval', seconds=20)
    threads = []
    th01.start()
    scheduler.start()
    threads.append(th01)
    threads.append(scheduler)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    print("End all process")
```

These 2 thread should run in the same time, but scheduler always need to wait until the Tkinter ends.

Comment: I believe that the moment you start Tkinter's main loop then nothing after that will run, so try putting the scheduler inside the main loop instead of after it.

Comment: @NatCecil But mainloop seems no more arguments to input and cannot run scheduler together now...So, multi-threading will be the choice.

Comment: It seems that, mainloop cannot be shut down until close it manually.

Comment: Yes, mainloop will close when root.quit is called

Comment: `root.after(20000, autoclick)`  will run `autoClick` after 20000ms (20s) so you can use this to execute function without scheduler.

Comment: @furas It seems doesn't work. And I wanna that, auotoclick() will be called every 20 seconds.

Comment: `root.after(20000, AutoClick)` runs function with delay only once. Inside `AutoClick` you have to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

In `tkinter` you can use `root.after(time_in_millisecond, function_name)` to execute function with delay. `root.after` executes function only once so inside this function you have to use `root.after` again.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import webbrowser
import pyautogui

def initialization():
    webbrowser.open('AutoRefreshSCMOutbound.HTML', 1)
    time.sleep(2)

def autoClick():
    # run again after 20000ms (20s)
    root.after(20000, autoClick)

    x, y = pyautogui.size()
    pyautogui.click(x/2, y/2, button='left')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(x/2, y/2, button='left')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('700x100')
    root.resizable(height = True, width = True)
    root.overrideredirect(False)

    OneBtn = tk.Button(root, command=initialization, text="One Button", width='30')
    OneBtn.grid(row=1, column=0)   

    # run first time after 20000ms (20s)
    root.after(20000, autoClick)

    root.mainloop()
```

OR using other function with `after()` to execute function which you don't want to modify.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import webbrowser
import pyautogui

def initialization():
    webbrowser.open('AutoRefreshSCMOutbound.HTML', 1)
    time.sleep(2)

def autoClick():
    x, y = pyautogui.size()
    pyautogui.click(x/2, y/2, button='left')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(x/2, y/2, button='left')

def repeate():
    # run again after 20000ms (20s)
    root.after(20000, repeate)
    autoclick()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('700x100')
    root.resizable(height = True, width = True)
    root.overrideredirect(False)

    OneBtn = tk.Button(root, command=initialization, text="One Button", width='30')
    OneBtn.grid(row=1, column=0)   

    # run first time after 20000ms (20s)
    root.after(20000, repeate)

    root.mainloop()
```

---

But `after()` is useful only if executed function doesn't run too long because it still blocks `mainloop()` (and rest of program) for this moment. Because `autoClick` uses `sleep(1)` so it stops all program for 1 seconds.

And `after()` is useful if other function doesn't runs too long because it may block `mainloop()` to execute functions added with `after()`. `initialization` use `sleep(2)` so it may block execution of `autoClick` for 2 seconds.

---

To run it without `sleep(1)` you can split function into two functions and use `after(1000, second_part)` to execute second part

```
def repeate():
    # run again after 20000ms (20s)
    root.after(20000, repeate)
    autoclick()

def autoClick():
    x, y = pyautogui.size()
    pyautogui.click(x/2, y/2, button='left')

    root.after(1000, autoClick_second_part) # 1000ms (1s)

def autoClick_second_part():
    pyautogui.click(x/2, y/2, button='left')
```

Comment: Yes! It works! and it does not need to use APScheduler module to do interval working. Thanks a lot! and I will study how to use multi-threading to realize it.